# Check or replace the value for the argument "palette" in the function ggplot2::discrete_scale()?

Tags: r, ggplot2, colors

Beforehand I want to apologize for my bad english...

I defined named, custom color palettes and want to easily call them with a self created function when creating a plot with the function ggplot(). Therefore I coded a "scale_function()" which only need 3 parameters:

```
type       (character. "color" or "fill" for aesthetic mapping)

palette    (character. Name of an available palette)

discrete   (logical. TRUE for discrete data and FALSE for continuous data)
```

With the help of a second function I use (grDevices::)colorRampPalette() to interpolate the given colors of a palette.

So far, everything is working just fine as planned. Now I noticed a very specific problem when using my function:

Let's say we want to create a plot, where we need less colors (n) than my selected color palette (c) actually has. This means n < c.

palette_catalog is a list and "palette_x" includes 6 different colors as hex-codes

```
palette_catalog[["palette_x"]]
# [1] "#d11141" "#00b159" "#00aedb" "#f37735" "#ffc425" "#cccccc"
```

#### plot

```
test <- ggplot(iris, aes(Sepal.Width, Sepal.Length, color = Species)) +
  geom_point() +
  scale_function(palette = "palette_x")
```

Now if I check the selected colors in the plot "test" I detected the following problem:

The first and last color (hex code) of a defined palette is correctly used but the color(s) in between will be interpolated because of the usage of colorRampPalette... hence the initial hex-code is overwritten with an interpolated, new hex-code.  --> that is the main problem! In the sake of consistency, ggplot2::discrete_scale() shouldn't behave like that...

If the plot needs more colors than the palette has to offer (n > c) the result is absolutely fine and correct, but I'd like to bypass the interpolation when n < c. In this case, discrete_scale() should call the needed colors of a palette in order of the defined colors within a palette, i.e. e.g.:

```
palette_catalog <- list(
  palette_x = c(
    "#d11141" (first value),
    "#00b159",
    "#00aedb",
    "#f37735",
    "#ffc425",
    "#cccccc" (last value)
  )
)
```

In a nutshell: if a plot demands e.g. 3 color values then I want discrete_scale() to pick the first, second and third value of "palette_x", instead of the first, interpolated mid and last value...

I am really sorry for my confusing english, I've tried my best to describe my problem and hopefully you can understand my point...

############### some code that should work (reduced to a minimum), just copy paste into your RStudio

---

```r
palette_catalog <- list(
  palette_x = c(
    "#d11141",
    "#00b159",
    "#00aedb",
    "#f37735",
    "#ffc425",
    "#cccccc"
  )
)


interpolate <- function(palette = "palette_x", ...) {
  x <- palette_catalog[[palette]]
  colorRampPalette(x, ...)
}

scale_function <- function(
    type = "color",
    palette = "palette_x",
    discrete = TRUE,
    ...) {

  count <- length(palette_catalog[[palette]])
  pal <- interpolate(palette)

  if(type == "color") {    
    if(discrete) {
      discrete_scale("color", palette, palette = pal, ...)
    } else {
      scale_color_gradientn(colors = pal(count), ...)
    }
  }
}


### use this code on this standard plot with iris dataset:

ggplot(iris, aes(Sepal.Width, Sepal.Length, color = Species)) +
  geom_point() +
  scale_function(palette = "palette_x")
```

[image]

```r
## you can print the used colors of a plot with the following code:
plot <- ggplot(iris, aes(Sepal.Width, Sepal.Length, color = Species)) +
  geom_point() +
  scale_function(palette = "palette_x")

gg <- ggplot_build(plot)

unique(gg$data[[1]]["colour"])
#      colour
# 1   #D11141
# 51  #799288
# 101 #CCCCCC
```

### expected (required) colors used for the 3 distinct species:

the first three color values of "palette_x" in that order:

```
"#d11141",
"#00b159",
"#00aedb"
```

### actual, incorrect colors used for the plot:

as already teased in the beginning the plot uses the first, mid (interpolated) and last color values...

```
"#d11141",
"#799288",
"#cccccc
```

As you can see the second color value is invalid because it is the result of a interpolation and doesn't match with the actual second value of "palette_x", which should be "#00b159".

Furthermore, the third color value is also unrequested. Instead, the actual third value should've been selected, which is "#00aedb".

I really hope someone can help me and find a solution! I am sure there is one.

I tried several solutions but none of them worked...

The code works just fine, as I already said. Just this tiny specific case is a pain in the ass and R drives me crazy at this point... because nothing works as I would expect it should...

I'd appreciate your help and support!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the following would give you approximately what you I think you are looking for. We simply write a new function within the function that returns the first 1:n values when n <= the length of the palette and otherwise interpolates the colours.

```
scale_function <- function(type = "color", palette = "palette_x", discrete = TRUE, ...) {

  pal <- interpolate(palette)

  palfun <- function(n) {
    if (n > length(palette_catalog[[palette]])) {
      return(pal(n))
    } else {
      return(palette_catalog[[palette]][seq_len(n)])
    }
  }

  if(type == "color") {    
    if(discrete) {
      discrete_scale("color", palette, 
                     palette = palfun, 
                     ...)
    } else {
      scale_color_gradientn(colors = pal(count), ...)
    }
  }
}
```

Your example will now look like the following:

```
g <- ggplot(iris, aes(Sepal.Width, Sepal.Length, color = Species)) +
  geom_point() +
  scale_function(palette = "palette_x")
g
```

[image]

With the following colours:

```
unique(layer_data(g)[["colour"]])
```

```
[1] "#d11141" "#00b159" "#00aedb"
```

And if you exceed the number of colours in the palette, it should start interpolating:

```
df <- iris
# Random discrete variable
df$catvar <- sample(LETTERS[1:10], size = 150, replace = T)

g2 <- ggplot(df, aes(Sepal.Width, Sepal.Length, color = catvar)) +
  geom_point() +
  scale_function(palette = "palette_x")
```

[image]

```
unique(layer_data(g2)[["colour"]]) # Not in right order due to random sampling
```

```
 [1] "#FDBB26" "#00B067" "#BC8359" "#00AFAF" "#E8C76F" "#CCCCCC" "#D11141" "#F6902F" "#5C694E" "#35A1B6"
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your solution!
I implemented the palfun() right away but I'm receiving a strange warning message, if I execute the ggplot(iris, ...):

"Warning message:
Removed 150 rows containing missing values (geom_point). "

And it displays a empty plot with just the axis and labels but without any geom asthetics or colors...

Why do I receive this warning? What does this mean?

Comment: It seems likely that the colours returned by the function would be NAs, which would give that error message. I've re-run the code on a different computer but it doesn't throw any error messages for me. Are you sure you've implemented the palfun() inside the scale_function() and not outside?

Comment: I've also re-run the code with the here posted excerpt of code. And it does work! But in my slightly expanded original version, the above mentioned warning message occurs... so there is something wrong in the additional code of mine which provokes this warning... Yes, I have definitely implemented palfun() inside my scale_function... Is there a possibility to share (or send) my entire code with you? Should I just post it here as a answer? Sorry for the dumb questions, I'm a rookie...

Comment: Never mind! I identified the source of the problem. I had to unname() my individual named list components. For every palette I also named every single color in the palette. For example: `base_colors <- c( "midnight" = "#000000, ...) and then palette_catalog <- list(  palette_x = base_colors[1:n] )`

So this simple change worked for me:

`palfun <- function(n) {
    if (n > length(palette_catalog[[palette]])) {
      return(pal(n))
    } else {
      return(unname(palette_catalog[[palette]][seq_len(n)]))
    }
  }`

Comment: thanks again for the support! I really appreciate it.

Comment: Good day teunbrand, do you think there is also way to implement a same logic for scale_color_gradientn()? In case the data is continuous and the used color palette provides more colors than actually needed for the interpolation? My current logic always interpolates with all available colors (count = length(palette)), i.e. pal(count). Is there a difference when I call pal with 256, pal(256)? Should I just create more palette variations to provide a workaround?

Answer (score 0):

Forgive me for misunderstanding, but I believe you can still use `colorRampPalette()`, but as a function:

```
pal_domains <- brewer.pal(name = "Set3", n = 12)
pal_function <- colorRampPalette(pal_domains)


ggplot(iris, aes(Sepal.Width, Sepal.Length, color = Species)) +
  geom_point() +
  scale_color_manual(values = pal_function(3))
```

and you can use `pal_function()` with any number of values, and change the palette name according to which one you want.

Comment: No problem, feel free to mark it as correct :) best of luck!